# How to call different functions when scrolled using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to call different functions using JavaScript when a key is pressed. It worked perfectly! How can I achieve the same effect by using the scroll wheel?

The goal is to change the background image of the webpage, carry out a query in a SQL Table and store the x and y co ordinates of the pointer in a table.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you able to post an example of something you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help :)

```js
$(document).scroll(()=>{
        if($(document).scrollTop() >= 970){
        //If you want to get style permenent remove line below
    $("body").css("background","red");
  }
      else if($(document).scrollTop() >= 508){
     //If you want to get style permenent remove line below
      $("body").css("background","blue");
  }
  else if($(document).scrollTop() >= 8){
     //If you want to get style permenent remove line below
      $("body").css("background","indigo");
  }
  })
```

```css
/*This is for smooth scrolling*/
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.big {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
.active {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div class="big" id ="home">Home</div>
<div class="big" id ="about">About Us</div>
<div class="big" id ="contacts">Contacts</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the `onscroll` and `scroll` event.

```
<div onscroll="myFunction()"></div>
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
```

and add the function in all cases:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("It works");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp